# Azure ServiceBus high amount of server errors in metrics

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

We are using Azure Service Bus in the West Europe region.

When I looked in our metrics to investigate a duplicating issue, I noticed that we have a high amount of "server errors". It's nearly 50% of the requests it seems.

Now there is not a lot of information regarding the meaning of server errors by Microsoft, other than saying it's "internal service bus errors" (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor)

[image: Metrics from Last 30 Days]

**My Question:**
Do I have to be concerned? Can I still rely on Service Bus in West Europe currently (there were some issues the last month in this region with Service Bus).

What does it mean and how can I solve it?

Thx in advance

Comment: It might be relevant to post the code you're using to send and receive messages from the Service Bus - possibly you are doing something that is causing errors to be logged here?

Comment: If these are trully "internal service bus" errors, I would try to investigate with Azure support. When it's something on the broker side, there would be a tracking ID logged along the error to speed up investigation.

Comment: Same situation...0 detail on what these are.

Comment: It's 2023, and there is still no clear documentation of this server's errors